# Find coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the power series expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)}$

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

I'm trying to find to coefficient of $x^{100}$ of
$$\sum_{n=0}^{∞}a_n x^{n}\ =\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)}.$$
I used the sum: 
$$\frac{1}{1-x}\ = 1+x+x^2+\ldots.$$
So : $$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)}= \left(1+x+x^2+\ldots\right)\left(1+2x+(2x)^2+\ldots\right)\left(1+3x+(3x)^2+\ldots\right).
$$
But multiplying out the right hand side to extract the coefficient $x^{100}$ is tedious. Any idea how I can obtain the coefficient in a simpler way ?

Regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use partial fractions: $$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x} - 4 \cdot \frac{1}{1-2x} + \frac{9}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-3x}.$$